# Academically reliable calculator of Gunning Fog Index

Tags: software, readability

Gunning Fog Index is used to estimate the *readability* of a sentence. Is the website [gunning-fog-index.com](http://gunning-fog-index.com/) reliable for academic research purposes? If not, what software should I use?

Comment: Is it really a "calculater"?

Comment: @AlexB. Isn't it? What would you call such software?

Comment: Shouldn’t it be a calculator?

Comment: @AlexB.You are right. It was a typo. Edited it immediately.

Answer (score 5):

The website clearly does not fulfill the requirements of *Reproducible Research*. The algorithm is not *Open Source* and the implementation isn't available for inspection.

There are more problems:

- The Website can go away without prior notice
- The implementation of the algorithm may change without notice

When you cannot find an Open Source implementation of the Gunning-Fox index, do it yourself. After all, the formula is not overly complex (though counting sentences and counting "complex words" can be tricky).

Comment: I am calculating the index for +30 sentences separately. Do you know any reliable software for this?

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no connections to this one and I did not test it, but I think this is worth looking at: https://pypi.org/project/readability/0.2/

Comment: There's a newer version of this now at PyPi, [this link](https://pypi.org/project/readability/) should always point to the most recent version.